# Firestore where() vs js filter(). what's the difference?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, filter

I have a question about querying data with where() in Firestore.
I wanted to write a query to an array of objects, but I found it impossible in Firestore with the where() function. So, I used the built-in filter() function to filter.

After the code below, I wondered the difference between where() and filter() when it comes to performance or readableness, and other variables.

Could any of you explain to me the difference?

```js
  const fetchFilteredNotMyQuotes = async () => {
    if (searchTagForNotMine) {
      setQuotesNotMine(
        quotesNotMine.filter((q) => {
          console.log(q.tags);
          if (q.tags) {
            return q.tags.some((tag) => tag.tag == searchTagForNotMine);
          }
        })
      );
    } else {
      getQuotesNotMine();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore's `where` clause may not be as robust as being able to run arbitrary function code in a client `filter`, but there are some good reasons to try figuring out a way to represent your data in a way that works with Firestore.

1. **Cost**: If you read the whole collection and then filter on the client, you'll be charged for each of the documents that was read from the server. If you on the other hand use a query, Firestore will only retrieve documents from the server that meet the where clause and you'll only be charged for those.
2. **Speed**: If you query a whole collection, you can end up with thousands of documents and you'll have to run a filter function on all of those. No matter what it'll be slower to run a function on more items than fewer. Additionally you may need to consider the performance profile of your client devices, that they not be as high-end as a cloud server to execute a lot of filters.

Perhaps you may want to come up with some hybrid architecture where you cast a wide, but not too wide, net on documents with Firestore and then perform a filter on a limited set of responses.

One other consideration would be adding the `limit` method to your queries for pagination purposes so that you don't need to request more documents than necessary.

Comment: Yes thanks for clarifying what I meant here.

Comment: All good.  and cleaning up comments...